# Implicit convert List<int?> to List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-entities

I am using Linq to Entities.

Have an entity "Order" which has a nullable column "SplOrderID".

I query my Orders list as

```
List<int> lst = Orders.where(u=> u.SplOrderID != null).Select(u => u.SplOrderID);
```

I understand it is because SplOrderID is a nullable column and thus select method returns nullable int.

I am just expecting LINQ to be little smart.

How should i handle this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As you are selecting the property, just get the value of the nullable:

```
List<int> lst =
  Orders.Where(u => u.SplOrderID != null)
  .Select(u => u.SplOrderID.Value)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

linq

```
var lst = (from t in Orders
           where t.SplOrderID.HasValue
           select new Order
           {
             SplOrderID = t.SplOrderID
           }).Select(c => c.SplOrderID.Value).ToList();
```

or

```
   var lst = (from t in Orders
               where t.SplOrderID.HasValue
               select t.SplOrderID.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: That makes a `List<Order>`, not a `List<int>`.

Comment: Now it's a `List<int?>`, not a `List<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question trying resolve the same problem, and after a few tries, i got this solution, cast `int` for each property on the list created by `select`

```
List<int> lst = Orders.where(u=> u.SplOrderID != null).Select(u => (int)u.SplOrderID);
```

Answer (score -1):

### Useful helper / extension method :

I usually use some helper extensions method for the jobs mentioned in the other answers :

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TKey> GetNonNull<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey?> keySelector) 
        where TKey : struct
    {
        return source.Select(keySelector)
            .Where(x => x.HasValue)
            .Select(x => x.Value);
    }

    // the two following are not needed for your example, but are handy shortcuts to be able to write : 
    // myListOfThings.GetNonNull()
    // whether myListOfThings is List<SomeClass> or List<int?> etc...
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetNonNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source) where T : struct
    {
        return GetNonNull(source, x => x);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetNonNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : class
    {
        return GetNonNull(source, x => x);
    }

}
```

Usage in your case :

```
// will get all non-null SplOrderId in your Orders list, 
// and you can use similar syntax for any property of any object !

List<int> lst = Orders.GetNonNull(u => u.SplOrderID);
```

---

### For the readers who don't want to simply ignore null values while converting

It's worth mentioning the potential use of `GetValueOrDefault(defaultValue)` yet, maybe you do you want to keep your original null values, but convert them to some default / sentinel value. (given as the `defaultValue` parameter) :

For your example :

```
// this will convert all null values to 0 (the default(int) value)
List<int> lst =
     Orders.Select(u => u.GetValueOrDefault())
     .ToList();

// but you can use your own custom default value
const int DefaultValue = -1;
List<int> lst =
     Orders.Select(u => u.GetValueOrDefault(DefaultValue))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: For downvoter : any explanation always appreciated so I can improve my answer .