# Fastest way to convert List<int> to List<int?>

Tags: c#, performance, linq

What is the fastest way of taking a list of primitives and converting it to a nullable list of primitives? For example: `List<int>` to `List<int?>`.

The easy solution, creating a new list and adding every item with a `foreach` loop, takes too much time.

Comment: what's your definition of too much time?  The only way is to loop (either with `foreach` or `LINQ`)

Comment: not to be smart, but aren't you able to refactor you code slightly so that you don't have to convert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit convert List<int?> to List<int>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394016/implicit-convert-listint-to-listint)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is no way faster than creating a new list:

```
var newList = list.Select( i => (int?)i ).ToList();
```

However using LINQ is slower than using a bare loop.

The fastest way is to use a `List<int?>` with pre-allocated capacity:

```
List<int?> newList = new List<int?>(list.Count); // Allocate enough memory for all items
foreach (var i in list)
    newList.Add(i);
```

If you are seeking for in-place type change of list items, it's not possible.

Comment: Well it would be faster not using LINQ.

Comment: @JeffMercado Actually, I agree :-) I've not measured the performance difference, but I guess it is negligible.

Comment: @Fuex Interesting. My test also shows that a bare loop is 30%-40% faster than LINQ (with 1,000,000) items.

Comment: Really how did you know iterating over items will outperform somethings like `Cast` method?! :)) I bet you didn't measured before!

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour I measured  This answer is for 7 years ago. I knew LINQ operators add some overhead, but I thought it is negligible. Now I have knowledge of all the overhead and also the compiler and runtime optimizations that may remove the overhead! Remember, you should **always** measure before optimizing!

Answer (score 16):

Instead of `Select` you can stick to the `Cast` LINQ-operator:

```
List<int> first = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
List<int?> second = first.Cast<int?>().ToList();
```

Comment: which is slower than `Select`

Comment: Could you prove that?

Comment: see the other answer on the same question

Answer (score 8):

If you want to know what's the faster solution, you should do a little [*benchmark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_%28computing%29) by using the three different ways:

```
List<int> list = Enumerable.Range( 0, 10000 ).ToList( );
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew( );

for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
   List<int?> newList = new List<int?>( );
   foreach( int integer in list )
      newList.Add( ( int? ) integer );
}

sw.Stop( );
TimeSpan timespan = sw.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Foreach: {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10 ) );
sw.Restart( );

for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ){
   List<int?> newList = list.Select( x => ( int? ) x ).ToList( );
}

sw.Stop( );
timespan = sw.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "LINQ-Select: {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10 ) );
sw.Restart( );

for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ){
   List<int?> newList = list.Cast<int?>( ).ToList( );
}

sw.Stop();
timespan = sw.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "LINQ-Cast: {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10 ) );
```

Results:

[image: Benchmark]

As we could expect the best way is the first solution (`foreach`) which means loop through the elements, cast and add them to a new list.

Comment: Have you tried it without foreach and using a simple "for(i = 0; i < list.Count();i++")? as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach

Comment: Interesting fact, so the SO-Answer I provided is a little bit out of date ;)

Comment: Don't forget to set the Capacity of the list in the foreach case to make it faster and leaner.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a new question, but I use this code currently; I share it with the hope that it could help others with the same question:
*List with pre-allocated + Linq*:

```
var branchIds = new List<int?>(branches.Count);
branchIds.AddRange(branches.Select(int.Parse).Select(brId => (int?)brId));
```

Comment: You don't show what `branches` is, but since you're converting it with `int.Parse` it must be some `string` collection, whereas the question is how to create a `List<int?>` from a `List<int>`.