# Convert Generic.List<int?> to Generic.List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures

I am returning a result set from a stored procedure. It is one temporary table that sends back a list of integers.

When I try to return the results I get an error `Generic.List<int?> to Generic.List<int>`

This is what I'm trying:

```
using (SecurityEntities ctx = new SecurityEntities())
{
    List<int> newList = ctx.spStoreSearch(storeNumber).Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x).ToList();
   return test;
}
```

under the `ctx.spStoreSearch(storeNumber).Where` section it says `Method, Delegate or event is expected`

I based what I've currently done on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394016/implicit-convert-listint-to-listint)

Could my error be in the stored procedure itself?
This is what I'm returning from the storedProc `select * from @TempTable`

Comment: what is the return type of spStoreSearch ?

Comment: "Method, Delegate or event is expected" Your file has `use System.Linq`, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select the value of Nullable int like:

```
.Select(x => x.Value)
```

You can also do casting like:

```
.Select(x => (int) x)
```

Your query could be:

```
List<int> newList = ctx.spStoreSearch(storeNumber)
                        .Where(x => x.HasValue)
                        .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

You are getting the exception because your element in the `List` is of type `int?` or `Nullable<int>` so when you do `Select(x=> x)` it is selecting items of type `int?` and you can't assign that to `List<int>`.

Comment: if this is the case, shouldn't the error message be different?

Comment: @Selman22, The error would be `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'` Why do you think the error would be different ?

Comment: @Selman22, never mind, I just concentrated on the title and thought that is the error OP is getting.

Comment: based on "When I try to return the results I get an error Generic.List<int?> to Generic.List<int>"

Comment: Thanks Habib, works perfect, as soon as time allows I will accept the answer, thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2):

Selects all not null values and add them into a list of integers (filtered out by using value property) .

```
//select int list
var nullableListIds = nullableListRecords.Select(o => o.ID).ToList();

//create list
var intList =  nullableListIds.Where(n => n != null).Select(n => n.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, you can either convert the nullable integers you have to 0 (or any other number that you decide to choose) and include them in your list or you can filter them out...

```
List<int?> nullableInts = new List<int?>();

// Lets generate some data to play with...
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int? digit = i % 2 == 0 ? (int?)null : i;
    nullableInts.Add(digit);
}

// Below we use the GetValueOrDefault method to convert all null integers to -1
List<int> ints = nullableInts.Select(x => x.GetValueOrDefault(-1)).ToList();

// Below we simply cast the nullable integer to an integer
List<int> filteredInts = nullableInts.Where(x => x.HasValue)
                                     .Select(x => (int)x).ToList();
```