# List<Guid> with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that returns a list of Guids. I want the following linq query in it:

```
var results = (from t in CurrentDataSource.Table1
               where t.Manager == userId && t.Profile != null
               select t.Profile).ToList();
```

Why do I get the following error:

```
Error   4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Guid?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Guid>'
```

Comment: Are you positive its being thrown from that line?  It doesn't look like it is.

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to convert a `List<Guid?>` to a `List<Guid>`, which can't implicitly be done.  I don't see how this line of code would be causing that error though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit convert List<int?> to List<int>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394016/implicit-convert-listint-to-listint)

Comment: just select `t.Profile.Value` instead to get a `Guid` instead of `Guid?` since you already filter out the `null` ones.

Comment: Post the line where the compilation error occurs. This code won't throw that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking if `t.Profile` is null, and only returning valid Guid's, so an explicit cast should work:

```
var results = (from t in CurrentDataSource.Table1
           where t.Manager == userId && t.Profile != null
           select (Guid)t.Profile).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you can't cast/convert a `List<Guid?>` to `List<Guid>`. You can use:

```
var results = (from t in CurrentDataSource.Table1
               where t.Manager == userId && t.Profile != null
               select t.Profile.GetValueOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ToList()` return a `List<Guid?>` without causing a compilation error? This code doesn't show any conversions between lists, unless `t.Manager` and `userId` are lists of GUIDs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: sure, the shown code compiles. But OP does something with this `List<Guid?>`, for example returning it as a `List<Guid>` or assigning it to a variable of that type. That code will not compile.

Comment: Fails against IQuerable though: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid GetValueOrDefault()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. An explicit cast however works.